# Data container to get range of large data

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers

I have a 3D object which has more than a 100000 points, these points have an id and x,y,z location values. I need to find the point ids of a specific x range where the y and z values are static.

eg -

```
 ---- --- --- --- 
| Id | x | y | z |
|----|---|---|---|
|    |   |   |   |
```

If I need to find the point ids between (x,y,z)

- p1 - 0.1   ,0.23, 0.78
- p2 - 123.0 ,0.23, 0.78

What sort of a data container should I use to achieve this efficiently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Juste a note : Be carrefull with the comparison of floating point values. Maybe you should define an epsilon range for the static values.

Comment: If the set of points is constant, you could keep this in an array sorted w.r.t `y,z,x` in the lexicographic order. Then a binary search should do.

Answer (score 1):

since 2 coordinates are always static, you can do with a simple sorted array for each coordinate, or a balanced [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (or [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)/ [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)/...) if you also need to support efficient addition/deletion. (Thinking of it, skip list would be probably easier to implement, just find first point in range, and iterate until you are out of range).

This will take `O(logN)` to query (if you need the actual points its `O(logN+k)`, where `k` are the points), and `O(NlogN)` initialization.

So, the algorithm would be:

1. Identify the non static point
2. Efficient search for the "Lowest" point in range
3. Efficient search for the "Largest" point in range
4. Return all points between them.

Complexity of 2+3 is `O(logN)`, and of 4 is `O(k)`, where `k` is the number of points returned (it cannot be avoided if you need the actual point, and not specific aggregation of them).